# imap cross platform issue

Tags: php, imap

I have develop a routine to open email boxes which are on different platform. It gives problem to open windows exchange if the code is running on linux  and vice versa. How I can resolve this issue. I am using the following code open IMAP.

```
$hostname = '{pop.lcn.com:110/pop3}INBOX';
$username = 'abc@xyz.co.uk';
$password = 'xxxxx';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to mail server: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,"ALL" );
```

particularly the mail box on this server was going to open the mail box. but now its not going to open and giving conneciton timeout problem. when I check it from windows server then it was working fine. Now I do not know what kind of changes have on server. that script is not running.

Comment: Little we can say with that little information you give. On first look it reads like a networking problem: maybe there is a firewall blocking your requests? Or the systems cannot communicate over network at all? Try testing network access to the imap port first using something like 'telnet pop.lcn.com pop3'.

Comment: If require any other info please let me know.

Comment: Likely, you simply cannot access the port remotely.  Many servers do not open the non secure ports.  Also, why are you connecting to POP3 if you want IMAP?

Comment: May I find any php open source email client which may help me? To open different type of connection.

Comment: @Max The php imap class implements several protocols: imap2, imap3, imap4, pop2, pop3, nntp and their ssl counterparts.

Comment: So instead of looking for a 'php open source email client', why not check first what the cause of the problem might be? Did you check the firewall hint I gave? Did you check access to the port using telnet as I suggested? Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes I have try telnet just now from ubuntu server, and its going to retrive email. I retrive a message through retr command. Its working fine.

Comment: That was server end issue they have resolve it. But they did not mention what was the issue. now mail box is going to open, same with old code.